# MS Access - Select records that dont exist in the same table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, in the first I enter the new applications, and in the second, I enter the comments after processing the application. The reason I designed it in this manner is to time-stamp the records.

In the Comments Table, I want to be able to **ONLY** select the Applications that have no comments in Comments Table. So I constructed the lookup query in `[02 BP Comments].[BP ID]` as shown in the image. Also, I set the bound column to 2; to select `[01 BP Applications].[BP ID]` but display `[01 BP Applications].[BP]`.

[Lookup Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g3NE.png)

> SELECT [01 BP Applications].BP, [01 BP Applications].[BP ID], [02 BP
>   Comments].[BP ID] FROM [01 BP Applications] LEFT JOIN [02 BP Comments]
>   ON [01 BP Applications].[BP ID] = [02 BP Comments].[BP ID] WHERE
>   ((([02 BP Comments].[BP ID]) Is Null));

However, when I use the comment table and enter a `[01 BP Applications].[BP]` value, I have to refresh each time to refresh the combobox. Also, after I refresh the database, the field `[02 BP Comments].[BP ID]` displays the bound value, `[01 BP Applications].[BP ID]`, instead of the display value, `[01 BP Applications].[BP]`.

I hope I explained it well ;-)

Anyway, how can I use the Comments Table without refreshing every time, while showing the display value, not the bound value?

Comment: Please try to extract the SQL code what your graphical query representation corresponds to.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a schema issue, it seems like a form design issue.

Comment: @Heikki
SELECT [01 BP Applications].BP, [01 BP Applications].[BP ID], [02 BP Comments].[BP ID]
FROM [01 BP Applications] LEFT JOIN [02 BP Comments] ON [01 BP Applications].[BP ID] = [02 BP Comments].[BP ID]
WHERE ((([02 BP Comments].[BP ID]) Is Null));

Comment: You should edit your question to include the SQL.

Comment: Common practice is to edit the question, so that it becomes more complete and understandable. Common practice is also to help editing the question with these kind of comments. There may be different people helping you to improve the question and providing the answer.

Comment: @nicomp
I'm going to design the form, but I want it to work even the table level

Comment: @Heikki
Im still new in Stackoverflow, please bear withe me :)

Comment: Your question in poorly constructed because you refer to a form but you want an answer unrelated to a form.

Comment: @nicomp
sorry if I spoiled your day =P. Anyway, I didn't refer to a form and I thought it could be done in tables.

Comment: @A_Alrumaidh You referred to refreshing a ComboBox in your question, which implies a form.

Comment: @nicomp
I dont want to argue more on this issue, but there are ComboBoxes in tables as well. Anyway, thanks for stopping by :)

Comment: @A_Alrumaidh You can argue or not, but a table has no combo boxes. That's a creepy feature of the Access table designer. What you're actually seeing is a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the SQL so [BP ID] is first column, set it as the BoundColumn and set ColumnWidths: 0";1.0";

`SELECT [01 BP Applications].[BP ID], [01 BP Applications].[BP],  FROM [01 BP Applications] LEFT JOIN [02 BP Comments] ON [01 BP Applications].[BP ID] = [02 BP Comments].[BP ID] WHERE ((([02 BP Comments].[BP ID]) Is Null));`

Cascading combobox - combobox with RowSource that is dependent on dynamic filter critiera - won't work in table because require code to requery the combobox for each record which cannot be behind table, only form. Cascading combobox with lookup alias won't work nice in continuous or datasheet form.